# Ajax check sent data

Tags: ajax, jquery

I am trying to send data with ajax. How can I see what is sent in data? I do not want to check on server side, but I want to test it for example in firebug, or alert. I want to see how data outputs, what will server side developer get with this ajax? This `order` is a string with numbers separated with coma `1,5,6,8`:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'server file url',
  data: '{itemOrder: \'' + order + '\'}',
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function () {
  alert("success");
},
       error: function (xhr, status, error) {
  alert(status);
  alert(xhr.responseText);
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could assign a `var dataToSend` equal to what you are preparing to send, and output it via `console.log(dataToSend)` or `alert(dataToSend)` right before your ajax call. Then in your call, just put it in place of what you had previously:

```
        $.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
             url: 'server file url',
             data: dataToSend,
             contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
             dataType: 'json',
             success: function () {
                 alert("success");
             },
             error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                 alert(status);
                 alert(xhr.responseText);
             }
         });
```

You could assign the variables as such:

```
var order = [1, 5, 6, 8];
var dataToSend = "{itemOrder:'" + order + "'}";
console.log(dataToSend);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How to put this in variable? itemOrder: \'' + order + '\'       What is the second part of this? i am trying to see how that looks

Answer (score 2):

use the network tools in chrome dev tools:

[LINK](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network)
Right click on the top bar and select TYPE and you should see the json requests and sends...

Look at watching the chrome dev tools videos presented by Paul irsh and Addy Osamni called: 
[FIRST VID](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ktwJ-EDiZoU)

If you log to console the "order" var it will dump in the console what it's trying to sen on success. 
the other way to do it would be to create a function out of the ajax call and then echo the whole function in the console.

```
 $.ajax({
                 type: 'POST',
                 url: 'server file url',
                 data: '{itemOrder: \'' + order + '\'}',
                 contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                 dataType: 'json',
                 success: function () {
                     alert("success");
console.log(order);
                 },
                 error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                     alert(status);
                     alert(xhr.responseText);
                 }
             });
```

Comment: ok, but how to check what it is trying to send? I want to know how this looks :)

Answer (score 2):

Just so you know you don't have to `console.log` or `alert`, you can do that if you prefer but you can check what is being sent to the server in the Network tab of your dev tools. See screenshot:

[image]

Select your ajax call and click Headers and click view source in request payload to see exact json object being sent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the developer tools found in every browser.
In Chrome right click on the top menu and select developer tools on the menu that pops.
Chose console when you are in developer tools then in the success function of your Ajax call `console.log()` your data